# Mudar background ao clicar e depois voltar a cor original

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, button

Estou com uma dificuldade no momento em que seleciono varios TextView, consigo mudar a cor normalmente e voltar quando o id é o mesmo do que foi selecionado.

Meu problema é o seguinte:

Quando eu mudo a cor do background de varios seguidos vai normal, porém se eu precisar voltar a cor do penultimo ou qualquer outro sem ser o ultimo botão que mudei o background é necessário que eu clique duas vezes. 
Preciso que no primeiro clique ela já mude o background.

Meu codigo está da seguinte forma:

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
public String buttonballsClick(View button){
    String tag = (String)button.getTag();
    int numeroInteiro = Integer.parseInt(tag);

    switch (numeroInteiro) {
        default:
            if (games.selectedTag == null || games.selectedTag != tag){
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.botao_lotecaa);
                games.setActualNumber(tag);
                games.selectedTag = tag;
            }
            else if (games.selectedTag.equals(tag)) {
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.botao_loteca);
                games.selectedTag = null;
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(ActivityLotecaCreateGame.this, "Houve um problema: " + tag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
    }
    return tag;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Edi!

Se eu entendi bem seu problema, você precisa que ao clicar novamente no botão a cor de background anterior volte. Sendo assim, faça da seguinte forma

1 - Crie um `selector` para cada botão, caso compartilhem estados diferentes, no diretório `drawables`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Um drawable para o estado de pressionado -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <!-- Um drawable para o estado normal do botão -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

2 - Adicione os `selector` aos respectivos botões

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/id_do_seu_botao"
   android:background="@drawable/selector_para_esse botao"
   android:layout_width="200dp"
   android:layout_height="126dp"
   android:text="Play" />
```

Utilizando isso, você abstrai o trabalho de ficar fazendo a troca de `background` e evita possíveis sobrecargas de memória.

Espero que isso ajude!